# Hosting using AddInProcess

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

Our application requires now that one of its components will be started in its own dedicated process.

I have just come across the [AddInProcess class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.addin.hosting.addinprocess%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (from System.AddIn.dll)

Unfortunately i couldn't find any useful code examples or projects that use this infrastructure.

I am wondering what are its pros/cons against rolling our own out of process infastructure?

Our application uses .NET 3.5 (WinForms)

The component that should be loaded out of process is an execution engine that loads arbitrary user code and executes it.

One note to consider is the fact that this component that executes code, needs to pass back a Results object to the calling application.

Comment: I think it would help to know a bit more about what sort of thing is in the component that needs it own process.  e.g. is it UI or services?

Comment: Updated my post. This component loads arbitrary user code, which may crash he process. This is, among few others, the motivation to isolate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on what sort of interface into the component you need.

If it is simple, i.e. the functionality needed is in a single function or two, you could just start a process to do it, passin an argument if needed.

If it is more complex, you could create a WCF host process and expose a service interface.

Comment: The process needs to return back objects to the calling application, i will specify that in the original post.

Comment: As ever, there are loads of ways to skin a cat, but WCF is a modern approach that would satisfy your needs.